# Xamarin.Firebase packages have the wrong folder structure on Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Project with an Android and an IOS App. I updated lately to the new versions of Xamarin.Firebase:

```
  <package id="Xamarin.Build.Download" version="0.4.7" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Analytics" version="4.0.5" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging" version="2.0.4.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core" version="4.0.13" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceID" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
```

Now I get the following message when I build on Visual studio for Mac: 
Could not find a part of the path "/Users/{User}/Library/Caches/XamarinBuildDownload/FAnlytcs-4.0.5/Frameworks/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics"

When I check the path in the message I see this structure:

[image]

I already deleted the packages from the solution and the cache and installed it again. But with the same result. The other firebase packages  do have a "frameworks" folder too much, but the file inside is correctly named.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the folder Cache I deleted all folders related to Xamarin (mainly Xamarin and XamarinDownloads) and checked the solution out again. Now it works.